# issue registering fluent validation in webapi2 via castle windsor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, castle-windsor, fluentvalidation

I have a class:

```
WebApiInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
```

which contains this:

```
container.Register(
                Classes
                    .FromThisAssembly()
                    .BasedOn(typeof(AbstractValidator<>))
                    .WithService
                    .Base());

var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(new WebApiInstaller());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(container);
```

in my global.cs file I currently use this:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(new WebApiInstaller());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(container);
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, provider => provider.ValidatorFactory = new WindsorFluentValidatorFactory(container.Kernel));
```

Here WindsorFluentValidatorFactory looks as follows:

```
public class WindsorFluentValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorFluentValidatorFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        return _kernel.HasComponent(validatorType)
             ? _kernel.Resolve<IValidator>(validatorType)
             : null;
    }
}
```

My endpoint looks like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult AddPointGivenGeoJsonPointDto([FromBody] Bla blaDto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Bla is decorated like this:

```
[Validator(typeof(BlaValidator))]
public class Bla
```

and the validator looks like this:

```
public class BlaValidator : AbstractValidator<Bla>
```

Unfortunately, the ModelState is never invalid despite invalid objects being passed in an integration test. Can anyone see anything wrong with my windsor.castle registration, which I think does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really hard to diagnose without stepping through the code in debug mode.

Its been a while since I've used castle windsor but one of the things i would suggest is to put a break point in your global.cs and add a reference to the container object in your watch window, after it has been configured through the **WindsorFluentValidatorFactory** class.

By doing this you can examine the container and all of its registered services. I know that with Castle Windsor, it also has a list of the services it failed to register and the reasons why they failed.

From my experience, it was generally the case that there was a missing dependency in the chain, and if one dependency doesn't register properly, any other dependency referencing it will fail also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the BlaValidator concrete registered as AbstractValidator<Bla>. I have the suspicion that: FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, provider => provider.ValidatorFactory = new WindsorFluentValidatorFactory(container.Kernel)); does not issue a validation for when I check ModelState.IsValid. Which part of the webapi live cycle checks if the modelstate.isvalid?

Comment: Model Binding is applied after Authorization Filters and before Action filters, (OnActionExecuting & OnActionExecuted).

Comment: Maybe I have to implement something here that triggers the validation? Ideally I want to come close to this: http://sergeyakopov.com/restful-validation-with-asp-net-web-api-and-fluentvalidation/

Comment: I would 100% go with this, I much prefer Ninject to Castle Windosr too, you could try and work this example to work with Castle Windsor, or just jump over to Ninject! :-)

Comment: I have to use Castle - still does not work despite config.Filters.Add(new RestfulModelStateFilterAttribute()); etc. thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks for this. It turned out that the castle windsor installer looked in the wrong assembly for the validator.